# basic potential problem in mechanics

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I am new to this field and I'm having trouble with this question where it asks me to calculate the potential from the basis of the origin. The question is:

$\overrightarrow{F} = (0, -2y + 3y^2,0)$

in $(x, y , z)$

I have no idea what should I do.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Start with $\vec{F}=\pm\nabla\phi$...

Comment: Are you familiar with line integrals? If so, you can construct a scalar potential function entirely mechanically.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find $\phi$ so that
$$(0, -2y+3y^2, 0) = \vec F = - \nabla \phi = - \left( \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z} \right) = \left( -\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}, -\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}, -\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z} \right),$$
i.e.
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} &= 0, \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} &= 2y-3y^2, \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z} &= 0.
\end{align}$$
Can you solve this? I recommend starting with $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} = 2y-3y^2.$

Comment: $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} = 2y-3y^2$, $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} = 2-6y$, $ \phi = (0,2-6y,0)$ , right ?

Comment: @Kat. Can you solve that? What form must $\phi$ have?

Comment: I am not sure how to answer it.

Comment: No, you are taking another derivative of the right hand side without showing that in the left hand side. Also, that is not the correct way. What if you had the following ordinary differential equation instead? Can you solve that?
$$f'(y) = 2y - 3y^2$$

Comment: sorry but I can't... how ?

Comment: @Kat. The solution to the last problem is $f(y) = y^2 - y^3 + C,$ where $C$ is some constant. Can you see that this is a solution to $f'(y) = 2y - 3y^2$? Perhaps it's easier if I use another variable and write $f(x) = x^2 - x^3 + C$ and $f'(x) = 2x - 3x^2$.

Comment: I see. thanks  so, $ \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}=y^2-y^3$ right?

Comment: Not $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}$. Something else equals $y^2-y^3$ plus another term. What is it that equals this expression?

Comment: I think it is $F_y$　grad

Comment: No, $F_y = -\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} = 2y-3y^2.$ It's $\phi$ that equals $y^2-y^3$ plus a term that doesn't depend on $y$. But since $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z} = 0$ it also doesn't depend on $x$ or $z$. Thus it's a pure constant, say $C$. Our final result is:
$$\phi(x,y,z) = y^2-y^3+C$$
for some constant $C$.

Comment: thanks a lot. that was so clarity answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$\underline{F}=-\text{grad}U$$
$$(0, -2y+3x^2, 0)^T=-(\partial_xU, \partial_yU, \partial_zU)^T$$
They are equal if and only if all of their components are equal:
$$0=-\partial_xU$$
$$-2y+3y^2=-\partial_yU$$
$$0=-\partial_zU$$
Where $U$ is the function of the position: $U(x, y, z)$
Now let's pick $1$ out of the $3$ equations, for example the first one:
$$0=\partial_xU$$
If we integrate both sides with respect to $x$ we will get that
$$U=f(y, z)$$
Where $f(y, z)$ can be any function of $y$ and $z$.
Now let's substitute this $U$ into another equation, for example into the second one:
$$\partial_y U=\partial_y f(y, z)=2y-3y^2$$
Integrating both sides with respect to $y$ we will get that
$$f(y, z)=y^2-y^3+g(z)$$
Where $g(z)$ can be any function of $z$. Now let's substitute it into the third equation:
$$\partial_zU=\partial_z(y^2-y^3+g(z))=g'(z)=0$$
And I think you can solve it for $g$, and you can put everything together to get $U$.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But, what is that T of (0,−2y+3x2,0)T ?

Comment: @Kat T means the transpose. It transforms the row vector to column vector. You can just ignore it.